# JAMon do not work after serialization+deserialization

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing, jamon

The flow of my performance testing needs JAMon monitor to go through these steps:

1. created,
2. serialized
3. deserialized
4. deserialized copy to be stopped

But the following scenario do not work (step 4 has no effect).

Could you provide me a workaround?

**Proof with code**:

```
public class Main {

    protected static void monitorSomething() throws InterruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Monitor outerMonitor = MonitorFactory.start("outerMonitor");
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            Monitor inner = MonitorFactory.start("myInnerMonitor");
            Monitor serializedMonitorSource = MonitorFactory.start("serializedMonitor");
            Thread.sleep(100+i);
            byte[] serialized = serialize( serializedMonitorSource );
            Monitor serializedMonitorDestination = (Monitor)deserialize( serialized );
            serializedMonitorDestination.stop();
            inner.stop();
        }
        outerMonitor.stop();
        MonitorFactory.start("mySecondMonitor")
                      .stop();

    }

    protected static void printPerformanceMeasurements(){
        for( Object monitor: MonitorFactory.getMap().values() ){
            System.out.println( monitor );  
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        monitorSomething();
        printPerformanceMeasurements();
    }

    private static byte[] serialize(Serializable serializable)  throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
            out.writeObject(serializable);
            byte[] messageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
            return messageBytes;
        }

    }

    private static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
             ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
            return in.readObject();
        }         
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
JAMon Label=myInnerMonitor, Units=ms.: (LastValue=114.0, Hits=10.0, Avg=114.2, Total=1142.0, Min=105.0, Max=136.0, Active=0.0, Avg Active=1.0, Max Active=1.0, First Access=Thu Feb 25 22:01:38 EET 2016, Last Access=Thu Feb 25 22:01:39 EET 2016)
JAMon Label=outerMonitor, Units=ms.: (LastValue=1143.0, Hits=1.0, Avg=1143.0, Total=1143.0, Min=1143.0, Max=1143.0, Active=0.0, Avg Active=1.0, Max Active=1.0, First Access=Thu Feb 25 22:01:39 EET 2016, Last Access=Thu Feb 25 22:01:39 EET 2016)
JAMon Label=mySecondMonitor, Units=ms.: (LastValue=0.0, Hits=1.0, Avg=0.0, Total=0.0, Min=0.0, Max=0.0, Active=0.0, Avg Active=1.0, Max Active=1.0, First Access=Thu Feb 25 22:01:39 EET 2016, Last Access=Thu Feb 25 22:01:39 EET 2016)
JAMon Label=serializedMonitor, Units=ms.: (LastValue=0.0, Hits=0.0, Avg=0.0, Total=0.0, Min=1.7976931348623157E308, Max=-1.7976931348623157E308, Active=10.0, Avg Active=0.0, Max Active=0.0, First Access=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970, Last Access=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970)
JAMon Label=com.jamonapi.Exceptions, Units=Exception: (LastValue=0.0, Hits=0.0, Avg=0.0, Total=0.0, Min=1.7976931348623157E308, Max=-1.7976931348623157E308, Active=0.0, Avg Active=0.0, Max Active=0.0, First Access=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970, Last Access=Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970)
```

Note that none of serializedMonitor is measured (active=10)

Comment: Because after deserialization there is no relation to the current jamon instance. After deserialization you have a new instance of everything that got serialized.

Comment: 10x for the replay. How to workaround this?

Comment: Workaround what? You shouldn't be serializing those things in the first place.

Comment: if you cannot contribute to the question, please do not spam

Comment: Why is this spam, if you serialize java objects you take a snapshot of everything inside that, when deserializing you will get a new object and for all referenced objects. What you want will simply not work...

Comment: If you do not see a solution, that does not mean there are no solutions. For example only monitor’s ID could be serialized and in step 4, the producer (MonitorFactory) could be searched for that ID. After it is found, the original monitor could be stopped.

Comment: Or you could detach the deserialized instance from new MonitorFactory and attach it to the original one. Then stopping the monitor will go fine.

Comment: Or you could extract start moment from the deserialized monitor, create new monitor and overwrite its start moment with that value and execute the stop.

Comment: That would be a new one, and the old one would still be active.

Comment: I recommend you check what workaround means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to serialize not the whole Monitor object, but only the start moment. At the measuring point, you could deserialize that moment and calculate the time difference from now. Then add the calculated value to MonitorFactory statistics pool.

You get time execution statistics (min,max,avg). The drawback is that you lose statistics of active executions.

Example code:

```
//            Monitor serializedMonitorSource = MonitorFactory.start("serializedMonitor");
        Date measuringStartOriginal = new Date();
        byte[] serialized = serialize( measuringStartOriginal );
        Thread.sleep(100+i);
//            Monitor serializedMonitorDestination = (Monitor)deserialize( serialized );
        Date measuringStartDeserialized = (Date)deserialize( serialized );
//            serializedMonitorDestination.stop();
        Date measuringEnd = (new Date());
        long timeDifference =  measuringEnd.getTime() - measuringStartDeserialized.getTime();
        MonitorFactory.add( "timeDifference", "ms", timeDifference );
```

Result:

```
JAMon Label=timeDifference, Units=ms: (LastValue=110.0, Hits=10.0, Avg=106.3, Total=1063.0, Min=102.0, Max=110.0, Active=0.0, Avg Active=0.0, Max Active=0.0, First Access=Mon Feb 29 10:43:57 EET 2016, Last Access=Mon Feb 29 10:43:58 EET 2016)
```